# Can Euler's formula be said to express the multiplicative identity of $x$ when $x = 2\pi$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, field-theory

Normally, the multiplicative identity of $x$ is derived by dividing $x$ by itself or multiplying it by its inverse.
However following Euler's identity,

$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$

Can Euler's formula for $2\pi$,

$e^{2\pi i} =$ cos $2\pi + i$ sin $2\pi = 1$

be said to express the multiplicative identity of $2\pi$ via addition?

Comment: Adding same quantity to the exponent is multiplicative ( squaring)  by  the multiplicative law  of indices in general, not only for  Euler's identity in particular.

Comment: What do you mean by "the multiplicative identity of $2\pi$"?

Comment: @Robert Israel I mean is the formula in this case equivalent to $\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}$? Are we showing something multiplicative by saying it additively?

Comment: For any integer $n$, $e^{2\pi in}=1$, so $e^{\pi in}=e^{-\pi in}$. Or are you trying to make another point?

Comment: Do you maybe want to say that $e^{2\pi i} = (e^{\pi i} ) ^2 = (-1)^2 = 1$ ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "equivalent to $2\pi/2\pi$." _Equivalent_ has specific meanings; for two expressions defining the same real number we'd normally say _equal_. But regarding addition and multiplication, maybe you're trying to get at the homomorphism property $$e^{i(x+y)}=e^{ix} e^{iy}\quad\text{for all real $x$, $y$.}$$

Comment: @J.G. Euler's identity is noted for including the multiplicative identity $1$. My question is how, if at all, is the appearance of $1$ in $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ related to multiplicative identity, which is something traditionally associated with multiplication and division?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the multiplicative identity of $x$". There is only _the_ multiplicative identity, which is the number $1$.

Comment: "Identity" has two different meanings. It could mean an equation that's true for all values of its variables, or it could mean a special number (or matrix etc.).

Comment: @mr_e_man Thanks for clarifying. In that case, can Euler's formula be said to express multiplicative identity when $x=2π$?

Comment: $e^{2\pi i} = 1$, and $1$ is the multiplicative identity.

Comment: @MBJ OK. The significance of $1$'s appearance in an equation of the form $x+1=0$ is simply $x=-1$. The only reason we usually use the former expression in this case is it's felt to make the equation more beautiful. $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ uses the five important numbers $0,\,1,\,e,\,\pi,\,i$, the three important operations $+,\,\times,\,{}^\wedge$ and the important relation $=$ once each.